# Preview's "save document" modal dialog obscures the image being saved

Tags: preview

I am closing *Preivew* but have many unsaved documents. When doing *Cmd-Q* an option to  "Review unsaved documents" is presented. It cycles through all the unsaved documents - but with a modal dialog in front of the document thus obscuring the contents,

I would like to pick and choose which ones to save. It is difficult to do so given the "save as" dialog is squarely in front of the image *and without any window handles to move it aside* :

[image]

Has anyone found a workaround for this?

Comment: @Tetsujin Updated the question to clarify: this is not my choice but the "Review unsaved documents" that cycles through all unsaved docs.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense, thanks. I don't know of any way round that, except to sort & save before you Quit.

Comment: What does "sort and save" mean here?

Comment: Choose which to save & which to close before you Quit, before you're forced to try see past that file-picker dialog.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yes that's possible but it's inconvenient vs having _Preview_ bring all of them up automatically. I just would like to be able to _see_ the documents.

Comment: I know of no way to detach that drop sheet. I have a file-picker enhancer [DefaultFolder] & even that can't do it.